# Computing the Rank of a Matrix of Functions

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find the rank of the matrix $$
 f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos (x) & -y\sin (x) \\
 \sin (x) & y\cos (x) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Defined on $\Bbb R^2$? And of matrices of similar form. Thank you

Comment: The rank of an $m \times n$ with $m > n$ is the maximum of the ranks of its $n \times n$ minors.

Comment: How do you work out the ranks of the nxn minors when the entries are functions of x and y?